# CSS border differences between browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm making a dropdown menu in pure CSS and I'm encountering some difficulties making the dropdown look the same in every browser.

I've tried everything I can think of - setting margins to zero, setting padding to zero... and nothing seems to work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mf9cS/

Safari renders it perfectly:

[image]

Firefox has a mysterious gap between the title and the dropdown:

[image]

And Chrome is missing one pixel out of the border on the top right concave corner:

[image]

CSS:

```
.container {
    position:absolute;
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    margin:0px;
}
.title {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    height:25px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:15pt;
    padding:0px;
    padding-top:1px;
    margin:0px;
}

.title:hover {
    height:200px;
}

.title:hover > .links {
    width:150px;
}

body {
    font-size:14pt;
}

.links {
    width:0px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    visibility:hidden;
    padding-top:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
}
.titletext {
    margin-left:0px;
    margin-top:0px;
    height:25px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.title:hover > .titletext {
    border:1px solid grey;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
}
.title:hover > .links {
    visibility:visible;
}

a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:grey;
    width:150px;
    display:block;
}

a:hover {
    background-color:purple;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="title">
            <span class="titletext">
                This is a test
            </span>
            <div class="links">
                <a href="">Link 1 </a>
                <a href="">Link 2 </a>
                <a href="">This is the third link</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _“Firefox has a mysterious gap between the title and the dropdown”_ – there is absolutely nothing “mysterious” about this, that is simply the white border-bottom you gave the `.titletext` element on hover …

Comment: The gap appears to be 2px high, and the border-bottom is 1px high, which means there's 1px seemingly coming from nowhere

Comment: In your screenshot it does, one the left side at least – but in my Firefox (latest version 29.0.1/Win7) it does not. Make the border red instead of white, then it should become clear what effect it has and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is your white border of title span element. All browsers are rendering border different way. In chrome and firefox that white border is touching to end of that element where you see white space at corner. Set border radius to 2px it the space will go away. I'm sure but here is the demo.

```
`border-bottom-right-radius:2px`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mf9cS/3/